# Convert html to PDF with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

I using wkhtmltopdf tool to convert html to pdf. On my linux computer it outputs everything right with css rules. But after installing the same tool on a Mac, the output does not look the same. The bold tag  does not work. The margin to the top does not work and the font size over all looks smaller.

What can be the problem here? The html file is very simple and I think the wkhtmltopdf should behave the same way here independent of platform.

Here is a part of the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      td {
        border:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
        background:white;
        padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt;
        height:19.65pt;
      }
      td.table_header {
        background:#D9D9D9;
      }
      .text_right {
        text-align: right;
      }
      table {
        width: 100%;
        border-collapse:collapse;
        border:none;
        line-height: 80%;
      }
      html {
        background:white;
        font-family: "Arial Unicode MS", sans-serif;
      }
      .header {
        font-size:18.0pt;
        text-align:center;
      }
      .address1 {
        text-align:right;
      }
      .text {
        line-height: 160%;
      }
      .space {
        line-height:80%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body style="margin:100px 100px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

A mismatched tag could be the source of the error. Carefully look through your code to ensure there isn't an opening tag without a corresponding closing tag or vice versa.